# Does Solana support any typed data schemes (e.g. EIP712)?

Tags: transactions

Sorry, newbie to Solana development.

Does Solana support any typed data schemes like EIP712. I see that they have this on the official docs (https://docs.solana.com/cli/sign-offchain-message). However, do any wallets support that currently?

Answer (score 0):

i guess almost all wallets support signing message, it's a pretty basic feature.

You can check this excelent video if you want to learn more about signing messages: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHkOQeSr4MM

Comment: Thanks, but I was more wondering about typed signing such as EIP 712? Not just simple message signing.

Comment: Oh, then sorry, i don't know about how ETH dev works, so can't really help i guess :/